# Combo Box if statement

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-c#-express-2010

I am having a problem with a combo box here. What I did is made a combo box, added items using `comboBox1.Items.Add("Something");`. Now I made a text box down there and what I need is when I select something from the combo box the text box changes according to selected item on combo box. What I thought it would do is

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Something")
{
    textBox1.Text = "Something";
}
```

But it's not working for some reason, I tried both without `ToString()` and with still it is not working.

Comment: is this WPF,WinForm, ASP.NET?? tag it correctly

Comment: What's the value of the call to .ToString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using: 
       `comboBox1.SelectedText`

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedText == "Something")
{
      textBox1.Text = "Something";
}
```

Comment: Yes. To clarify, SelectedItem is an item, not a text.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on your combobox and it will generate event for you(`SelectedIndexChanged` by default). **put your code inside that generated event**. When you change combobox selected value then you can see the text box value change accordingly.

if you need to show combobox selected value in the textbox, you can put below code inside generated event

```
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: if you add string as item, this is working fine, selectedItem is a string since OP adding `comboBox1.Items.Add("Something");`

Answer (score 1):

Oh found the problem . I was putting the code in wrong section (on textBOx_click) section :P

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "Something")
{
    textBox1.Text = "Something";
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

OR a consice version

```
textBox1.Text = 
comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "Something" ? "Something" :"";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Something")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Something";
            }
        }
```

Comment: try this:  
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "something")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Something";
            }
        }

Comment: I did use the same code as before but under ComboBox SelectedIndexChange and it worked , i was typing under textBox1_Click evvent handler

Answer (score 0):

According to your question I suppose that whatever the `selectedItem` is you want to display it on the `TextBox`. So, why don't you use this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "M.Naveed")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("mobile");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("mobile");
            ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem("Networking");
            li.SubItems.Add("mobile");
            listView1.Items.Add(li);


        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Zeeshan")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Jave");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Jave");
            ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem("Networking");
            li.SubItems.Add("Jave");
            listView1.Items.Add(li);

        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Shamsher")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Networking"); textBox1.Text = " ";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Web");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Web");
            ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem("Networking");
            li.SubItems.Add("Web");
            listView1.Items.Add(li);



        }

        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Mudasir")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Networking");
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Team Fundation");
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + ("Team Fundation");
            ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem("Networking");
            li.SubItems.Add("Team Funadation");
            listView1.Items.Add(li);


        }


        }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Someting");

        comboBox1.Items.Add("Mcs");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("M.Naveed");
        comboBox1.Items.Add ("Mudasir");
        comboBox1.Items.Add ("Zeeshan");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Shamsher");



    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Dr")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("its dr");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("its cr");
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox2.Text == "Dr")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("its dr");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("its cr");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your InitializeComponent() add this

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
//
// combobox
//
this.combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.changed);
}
```

then in your main method, create this method

```
private void changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(this.combobox.Text == "Something")
Textbox1.Text = "Something";
}
```